# How to get Skewness and/or Kurtosis in MS Access 2013?

Tags: sql, ms-access

How do you get skew and kurtosis in MS Access 2013?

My tblFirst250 has column GM which can be Null and has a data range of roughly -5 to 5. Every value in IU is either 1 or NULL.

I am trying to get the skew and kurtosis of the GM column of my table when a record for IU = 1.

(I couldn't find skew and kurtosis here so I am adding it for the next person who needs it.)

Comment: I like your idea, but the question is basically useless. I can go to the link and find better information. I suggest you provide some sample data, and what you're doing with that data, and how it can be used. Otherwise it's not much better than a link-only answer. **TL;DR**: You give no context of `T1`. What does the data look like?

Comment: I think you should use a statistics package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you get them:

```
SELECT t1.IU, 
    (Sum((t1.GM-z.TheAvg)^3)/Count(t1.GM))/(Sum((t1.GM-z.TheAvg)^2)/Count(t1.GM))^1.5 AS Skewness, 
    (Sum((t1.GM-z.TheAvg)^4)/Count(t1.GM))/(Sum((t1.GM-z.TheAvg)^2)/Count(t1.GM))^2 AS Kurtosis
FROM tblFirst250 AS t1 INNER JOIN 
    [SELECT t1.IU, Avg(t1.GM) AS TheAvg
    FROM tblFirst250 t1 GROUP BY t1.IU]. AS z ON t1.IU = z.IU
GROUP BY t1.IU
HAVING Count(t1.GM) > 0;
```

Adapted from:
http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/2529/Median-Mode-Skewness-and-Kurtosis-in-MS-Access.html

Comment: Although the formulas a technically correct, you should probably consider a real statistics package.  The accuracy of numeric results is highly dependent on the algorithm used to generate them, and this formula may not work correctly on larger data sets.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - like R?

Comment: Like R.  Caveat:  I don't actually know how R implements these particular functions, but statistical packages are generally more sensitive to the issue of numerically stable algorithms.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Curious why you think this may not work on larger data sets?

Comment: . . (I did upvote the answer because it is easy and technically correct).  The reason is because of numeric overflow and numeric stability.  If you start to add millions of numbers, the addition might start to overflow the ability of floating point number to represent both sums and sums of powers *and* smaller values.  If you are interested in the subject, this might be a place to start:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis.